# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name_' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel

Buenas tardes a todos

Estoy aprendiendo **laravel** por mi cuenta y por la web y la documentación oficial pero tengo una inquietud:

Resulta que hice una gestión de usuarios donde agrego roles y los roles tienen niveles etc. si dejo mi pc por un rato y se pone a invernar cuando regreso el sitio esta donde lo deje y todo pero al parecer las sesiones se sierran y me envía al login e inicio sesión de nuevo y al re-dirigirme a la pagina donde de se quedo ejemplo a https://sitio.test/user/create me sale este error:

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name_' in 'field list' (SQL: select`name_`,`id`from`job_levels`where`name_en`!= God and`doctor`= 1)`

Tengo que irme a la raíz y volver a entrar a https://sitio.test/user/create y ya todo funciona normal

controlador

```
public function create()
    {
            $JLevels = \DB::table('job_levels')
            ->where('name_en', "!=", "God")
            ->where('doctor', '=', '1')
            ->pluck('name_'.session()->get('locale'), 'id');

            $Roles = \DB::table('roles')
            ->where('name', "!=", "God")
            ->pluck('name', 'id');

            $Permission = Permission::where("category", "!=", "roles")->get();
            $Categories = \DB::table('permissions')->select('category')->where("category", "!=", "roles")->distinct()->get();
            return view('user.create', compact('Permission', 'JLevels', 'Categories', 'Roles'));
    }
```

ruta

```
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
```

¿Alguna ayuda o idea?

Index de UserController

```
 class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('can:user.create')->only(['create', 'store']);
        $this->middleware('can:user.index')->only(['index']);
        $this->middleware('can:user.edit')->only(['edit', 'update']);
        $this->middleware('can:user.show')->only(['show', 'showModaiInfo']);
        $this->middleware('can:user.destroy')->only(['destroy']);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            // $users = User::get(['name', 'telephone', 'email', 'color', 'username']);
            $users = \DB::table('users')
            ->where('username', '!=', 'soporte')
            ->join('job_levels', 'users.job_level_id', '=', 'job_levels.id')
            ->select('users.id','users.name','users.username','users.telephone','users.email','users.color','users.created_at','users.updated_at', 'job_levels.name_'.session()->get('locale'))
            ->orderBy('users.id','asc')
            ->get();

            return DataTables::of($users)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('name', function($users){
                    $name = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:'.$users->color.'"></i> '.$users->name;
                    return $name;
                })
                ->addColumn('action', 'user.actions')
                ->addColumn('level', function($users){
                    if (session()->get('locale') == 'es') {
                        $level = $users->name_es;
                    } elseif (session()->get('locale') == 'en') {
                        $level = $users->name_en;
                    }
                    return $level;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action', 'level', 'name'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view('user.index');
    }

}
```

HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $locale = auth()->user()->lang;
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        setcookie ("lang", $locale, time() + 525600);

    }
     public function lang($locale)
    {
        $id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->lang = $locale;
        $user->save();
        App::setLocale($locale);
        setcookie ("lang", $locale, time() + 525600);
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

web.php

```
App::setLocale(Cookie::get('lang', App::getLocale()));



 Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    } else{
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
});


    Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'HomeController@lang');

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
});
```

Comment: Desde dónde guardás `locale` en la session? Probablemente lo estés haciendo en el index. Tu session está vacía por haberte deslogueado, y como vas directo a `user/create` nunca guardás `locale` en la session. Revisá eso, lo idea sería guardar `locale` desde algún lugar común, como un middleware. Y sino, al menos poné algún valor por defecto si no existe.

Comment: @azeós Edite la pregunta con el index pero la variable locale e la que guarda el idioma que se esta visualizando el sitio!!

Comment: Entiendo lo que hace locale, lo que no veo es _donde_ la estás guardando, porque en el index la traes, pero no la generas. Desde dónde lo hacés?

Comment: en el HomeController y lo uso ahi porque en la pase de datos tiene name_es y name_en y locale guarda en o es y si es un middleware

Comment: Entiendo, entonces sacá el `UserController` y publicá tu `HomeController`. El punto es que NO deberías hacer eso en un cotrolador, al menos no en uno puntual, podrías hacerlo en `Controller`. Necesitás que la sesión esté cargada siempre, si la lógica la tenés en un controlador específico, vas a tener ese tipo de problemas. Insisto, lo ideal sería hacerlo en un `middleware` (entiendo). Publicá tu archivo de rutas.

Comment: Entiendo, pero no se como hacer que esta variable se cargue desde Controller es decir casa usuario registrado tiene un preferencia de idioma debería poder iniciar la variable en Controller y recuperarla donde se requiera.

Comment: Publicá tu `HomeController` así vemos como lo estás haciendo. Cómo define su idioma cada usuario?

Comment: Listo edite la pregunta con HomeController y rutas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tenés que hacer es extraer la lógica que detecta el idioma del usuario y llevarla a un lugar común. Te muestro como hacerlo desde un controlador.

**Controller:**
Ésta clase es la que usan el resto de los controladores como base, con lo cual, lo que hagamos dentro va a estar disponible para todos. Dejá lo que tenga y solo sumá el `__construct()`.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Si no se guardó nada en la sesión, lo hacemos
        if (! session('locale')) {
            // Si el usuario está logueado obtenemos su idioma, sino levantamos por defecto el del sistema
            $locale = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->lang : app()->getLocale();
            app()->setLocale($locale);
            session(['locale' => $locale]);
            setcookie('lang', $locale, time() + 525600);
        }
    }
}
```

No se para que estás guardando además una cookie, si no la estás usando, borrala.

En el caso que el controlador que estés utilizando tenga definido un `__construct()`, tenés que llamar al padre dentro del mismo:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        // Llamamos al __construct() padre
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Todo lo que estabas haciendo acá ya no hace falta
    }

    public function lang($locale)
    {
        // auth()->user() ya devuelve el usuario, no hace falta después buscarlo por ID
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->lang = $locale;
        $user->save();

        app()->setLocale($locale);
        session(['locale' => $locale]);
        setcookie('lang', $locale, time() + 525600);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Eso sería todo.

---

Deberías revisar algunas cosas de tu archivo de rutas. Probablemente `/dashboard` y `/lang` tengan que ir dentro del grupo con el middleware `auth`.

Por otro lado, no se bien como funciona `DataTables` del lado del servidor, pero me parece que tenés algunos errores.
`$users->color` y llamadas similares probablemente te devuelvan error porque `$users` no es *UN* usuario sino una *colección* de usuarios (por la llamada a la DB que tenés arriba).

Comment: Gracias, esta fue la solución solo agregue esta linea a mi UserController `parent::__construct();` y funciono